# Is it possible to count rising edges of a 4 MHz clock on an Arduino Due and trigger an interrupt like all 4'000'000 edges?

Tags: c++, c, arduino-due

I am struggling with my Arduino Due and the Timer Counter functionallity. The following is what I am trying to achieve:

I want to execute a function to a specific point of time or more precisley after a specific amount of rising edges given by an external clock signal with a frequency of approx. 4 MHz. Thus I read the Atmel Datasheet, Section 36, Timer Counter. My approach was to trigger an interrupt every rising edge and increment a counter variable until I reached the desired amount of rising edges and call my function then. I can confirm that I am in fact counting rising edges with my current approach but I am reading way too slow. Is there any kind of register or hardware counter which automates the counting process. Like I set the register to a specific value and wait for an overflow, execute my function and reset the register? From my web research I found that this is possible on the Uno and Mega but I could not find anything for the Due and to be honest I am a bit overwhelmed by the Atmel Datasheet. Why not just use an Arduino Due or Mega then? I need the 3.3 Volts of the Due and from what I found the Uno and Mega are 5 V devices.

This is my code:

```
// define capture channels
#define CAPTURE_TC TC0
#define CAPTURE_CHANNEL 0
#define CAPTURE_IRQn TC0_IRQn
#define CAPTURE_Handler TC0_Handler
#define CAPTURE_ID ID_TC0
#define CAPTURE_PIN 2
#define CAPTURE_CLOCK_SELECTION TC_CMR_TCCLKS_TIMER_CLOCK3

// clock divisors corresponding to CAPTURE_CLOCK_SELECTION
static const uint32_t divisors[5] = { 2, 8, 32, 128, 0};

volatile uint32_t captured_pulses = 0;
volatile uint32_t captured_ra = 0;
volatile uint32_t captured_rb = 0;
volatile float frequency, duty_cycle, active_time;

/*
* Function:  setup 
* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Setup code. Will be executed once.
*/
void setup() {

  // init serial connection
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("Initializing...");

  // configure the PIO pin as peripheral
  const PinDescription *config = &g_APinDescription[CAPTURE_PIN];
  PIO_Configure(config->pPort, config->ulPinType, config->ulPin, config->ulPinConfiguration);

  // enable timer peripheral clock
  pmc_enable_periph_clk(CAPTURE_ID);

  // configure the timer
  TC_Configure(CAPTURE_TC, CAPTURE_CHANNEL,
    CAPTURE_CLOCK_SELECTION   // Clock Selection
    | TC_CMR_LDRA_RISING      // RA Loading: rising edge of TIOA
    | TC_CMR_LDRB_FALLING     // RB Loading: falling edge of TIOA
    | TC_CMR_ABETRG           // External Trigger: TIOA
    | TC_CMR_ETRGEDG_FALLING  // External Trigger Edge: Falling edge
 );

  // configure TC interrupts
  NVIC_DisableIRQ(CAPTURE_IRQn);
  NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(CAPTURE_IRQn);
  NVIC_SetPriority(CAPTURE_IRQn, 0);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(CAPTURE_IRQn);

  // enable interrupts
  CAPTURE_TC->TC_CHANNEL[CAPTURE_CHANNEL].TC_IER = TC_IER_LDRBS;

  // start timer counter
  CAPTURE_TC->TC_CHANNEL[CAPTURE_CHANNEL].TC_CCR = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;

  Serial.println("ready!");

} // setup

/*
* Function:  loop 
* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Loop code. Will be executed repeatedly after setup completed.
*/
void loop() {

 // Serial.print("Captured rising edges: "); Serial.println(captured_ra);
} // loop

/*
* Function:  CAPTURE_Handler 
* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*
*/
void CAPTURE_Handler() {
 if ((TC_GetStatus(CAPTURE_TC, CAPTURE_CHANNEL) & TC_SR_LDRBS) == TC_SR_LDRBS) {
   captured_pulses++;
   // captured_ra = CAPTURE_TC->TC_CHANNEL[CAPTURE_CHANNEL].TC_RA;
   // captured_rb = CAPTURE_TC->TC_CHANNEL[CAPTURE_CHANNEL].TC_RB;

   if (captured_pulses == 4164303) {
    captured_pulses = 0;
    // specific_function_call(); 
   }
 }
} // CAPTURE_Handler
```

Thanks for your time, any help is grealty appreciated.

Comment: `Atmel Datasheet, Section 36, Timer Counter. My approach was to trigger an interrupt every` Are you sure you did read it? The timer is called "Timer Counter" because literally it has an internal... counter... so that you do not need to do something _every_ input.

Comment: @KamilCuk As I said I was overwhelmed by it. I guess Section 36.7.2 is the relevant part for me but I usually do scientifc computing, I'm pretty new to all this hardware stuff which is why I am asking for help.

Comment: Sure. Aim for the RC compare part, set the the compare counter to that 4164303 and just trigger the interrupt once every 4164303 cycles. Also you could divide input clock by some value.

Comment: Thanks for the input, gonna try it.

Comment: If I may ask, for what application you need it for ? Btw any microcontroller datasheet is painful to read

Comment: @Weldriv  Datasheets are a pain to read, but that's the minimum you need to do to use the devices effectively.  And don't forget to read the erratas.  There are always noce surprises there that may save you a couple of weeks of tries and failures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all excuse my inactivity but as you know it's crazy times right now. However I finally figured it out, it's for sure not the most elegant solution but it meets my requirements. Thanks for your help @KamilCuk.

Here is my code if anyone may ever have the same problem as I did. External signal goes on Digital Pin 2. Works fine with a 4.2 MHz external clock.

```
// define capture channels
#define CAPTURE_TC TC0
#define CAPTURE_CHANNEL 0
#define CAPTURE_IRQn TC0_IRQn
#define CAPTURE_Handler TC0_Handler
#define CAPTURE_ID ID_TC0
#define CAPTURE_PIN 2
#define CAPTURE_CLOCK_SELECTION TC_CMR_TCCLKS_TIMER_CLOCK3

/*
* Function:  setup 
* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Setup code. Will be executed once.
*/
void setup() {

  // init serial connection
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("Initializing...");

  // configure the PIO pin as peripheral
  const PinDescription *config = &g_APinDescription[CAPTURE_PIN];
  PIO_Configure(config->pPort, config->ulPinType, config->ulPin, config->ulPinConfiguration);

  // enable timer peripheral clock
  pmc_enable_periph_clk(CAPTURE_ID);

  // configure the timer
  TC_Configure(CAPTURE_TC, CAPTURE_CHANNEL,
    CAPTURE_CLOCK_SELECTION   // Clock Selection
    | TC_CMR_LDRA_RISING      // RA Loading: rising edge of TIOA
    | TC_CMR_ABETRG           // External Trigger: TIOA
    | TC_CMR_CPCTRG           // RC Compare
  );

  // configure TC interrupts
  NVIC_DisableIRQ(CAPTURE_IRQn);
  NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(CAPTURE_IRQn);
  NVIC_SetPriority(CAPTURE_IRQn, 0);

  // enable interrupts and start counter
  CAPTURE_TC->TC_CHANNEL[CAPTURE_CHANNEL].TC_IER = TC_IER_CPCS;                  // enable RC Compare Interrupt
  CAPTURE_TC->TC_CHANNEL[CAPTURE_CHANNEL].TC_CCR = TC_CCR_CLKEN | TC_CCR_SWTRG;  // the datasheet said I need this
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(CAPTURE_IRQn);                                                  // enable interrupts

  // set the trigger value for RC_Compare
  CAPTURE_TC->TC_CHANNEL[CAPTURE_CHANNEL].TC_RC = 4164303;

  Serial.println("ready!");

} // setup


/*
* Function:  loop 
* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Main code. Will be executed repeatedly.
*/
void loop() {

} // loop


/*
* Function:  CAPTURE_Handler respectively TC0_Handler 
* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Timer capture trigger. Will be executed if TC0_RA == TC0_RC 
*/
void CAPTURE_Handler() {
  // reset status register  
  TC_GetStatus(CAPTURE_TC, CAPTURE_CHANNEL);

  // do something
  Serial.println("Trigger");
  // function_call()
}
```